# Not getting desired output of print statement

Tags: java

In a second input "Enter a score. -1 to quit: " is missing and when a program end it appears.How to fix it?
Also, if there's a better way to write this program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class l
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int avgScore = 0;
        int entry = 0;
        int totalScore = 0;
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a score. -1 to quit: ");
            int score= in.nextInt();
            if(score == -1)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                totalScore +=score;
                entry++;
            }
        }
        while (in.hasNextInt());

    }
}
```

Comment: Change your `while` to `score != -1`

Comment: `while (score != -1);`

Comment: @notyou @anchreg `score` is not in that scope, it should be declared outside for your suggestions to work

Comment: figured he'd do that when a compile error occurs :)

Answer (score 1):

Your program prints out the message "Enter a score...", and then waits for and accepts an integer input, which is fine.

However, before the second iteration of the loop begins, your loop conditions checks whether the user has given **another** integer input **before** the message is printed for the second time, which is why the second iteration of your loop may begin only after you give some input to the program.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking `in.hasNextInt()` and a do-while-loop you can just use a simple for-loop without a breaking condition (or a `while(true)`-loop) and just call always `in.nextInt()`:

```
/* ... */
for(;;){
    System.out.print("Enter a score. -1 to quit: ");
     int score = in.nextInt();
     if(score == -1){
         break;
     } else{
         totalScore += score;
         entry++;
     }
}
/* ... */
```

Answer (score -2):

```
while(true){
 System.out.print("Enter a score. -1 to quit: ");
            int score= in.nextInt();
            if(score == -1)
            {
                break;
            }
 totalScore +=score;
                entry++;
 if(entry ==0)
        {
            System.out.println("average score: "+ totalScore);
        }
        else
        System.out.println("average score: "+ totalScore/entry);
    }
}
```

Comment: No explanation, using while(true) ...

Comment: Doesn't compile either